# Why is JQuery saving my field as blank when I set the field to disabled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

I have a sharepoint that I need to disable two of the fields on the Edit form.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 $("input[title='Issue ID']").attr("disabled", true);
 $("input[title='Issue Title']").attr("disabled", true);
```

The fields do get set to disabled however when the form saves my record shows that both the ID and the Title are now blank. I do not want to remove the data I just don't want the user to edit the information.

When is hide the row instead this doesn't happen. I did that using:

```
 $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Issue ID')").closest("tr").hide();
 $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Issue Title')").closest("tr").hide();
```

It seems abnormal that this happens. Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Per the answer below I changed my code to:

```
 $("input[title='Issue ID']").attr("readonly", true);
 $("input[title='Issue Title']").attr("readonly", true);
```

This fixes the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because *disabled* fields are actually not posted (they are not included in the post at all).

Instead try [readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-readonly-attribute) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

http://sympmarc.com/2010/10/08/using-jquery-to-prefill-and-disable-required-column-in-a-sharepoint-form/comment-page-3/#comment-114450

here you go bro this solution works like a magic hope you get it solved.

Comment: Please add more details. Links can get broken over time.

Comment: The PreSaveAction is an option. It really depends on what you are trying to do.